# How to flip a view with a label on the front side and another label on the back side - see image

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

How can I flip a view with a label on the front side and another label on the back side when a button is clicked? Something that looks like the image below.

What would be the logic to create this effect?
[image]

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry about the confusion but please note that I'm just talking about a view not ViewControllers, this effect will happen within the same viewController. I have updated the image to reflect that the view I'm talking about is a subView inside the main view.

Answer (score 2):

I too had something very similar situation, on click of a button on `ViewController1` I have to move to another `ViewController2`. I used this code,

```
//code this in ViewController1
-(IBAction)flipView:(id)sender
{
    ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [view2 release];
}

//code this in ViewController2 on click of back button
-(IBAction)flipView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

But in this code I am using 2 classes, if it is fine to you, use this code. Hopes it solves your problem to some extent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I'm understanding this correctly, what you are describing is basically a flip between two view controller. Something like the standard modal segue. See my updated image. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use two `UIView`s, one for the first side, one for the second side.

Show the first view, hide the second view, and set the second view's frame to have a width of 0.

Then, when your first view is visible, animate its frame to have a width equal to 0. Hide the first view, unhide the second view, and animate the second view's frame to the desired frame.

Edit : This does not appear to work well if you have labels in your views, as this is a 2D flip. Sorry about that. @Maverick's answer could work pretty well in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Call this method in your viewController, your viewController view flips and  viewController life cycle method calls and simply change the image of UIImageView you want to display in 
-(void)viewdidload method.

```
    [UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    UIView *parent = self.view.superview;
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.view = nil; // unloads the view
    [parent addSubview:self.view]; //reloads the view from the nib
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
    forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    Please vote up if you find it helping
```